# como saber si el servidor entro en un bucle

Tags: java, clase, socket, class, server

Tengo dos clases: una servidor

```
public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket servidor = null;
        
        Integer numeroSecreto = null;
        Integer numeroJugador = null;
        
        final Integer PUERTO = 2000;
        
        String respuesta = null;
        boolean acertado = false;
        
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        
        try {
            servidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);
            System.out.println("Esperando la conexión");
            
            numeroSecreto = GenerarNumero();
            System.out.println("Número secreto: " + numeroSecreto);
            
            while(!acertado){
                Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
                System.out.println("Conexión aceptada");
                
                dis = new DataInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
                dos = new DataOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
                
                numeroJugador = dis.readInt();
                
                if (numeroJugador == numeroSecreto){
                    System.out.println("Has acertado");
                    acertado = true;
                    respuesta = "BINGO";
                    dos.writeUTF(respuesta);
                } else if (numeroJugador < numeroSecreto){
                    System.out.println("MAYOR");
                    respuesta = "MAYOR";
                    dos.writeUTF(respuesta);
                } else if (numeroJugador > numeroSecreto){
                    System.out.println("MENOR");
                    respuesta = "MENOR";
                    dos.writeUTF(respuesta);
                }
            }
            
            servidor.close();
            dis.close();
            dos.close();
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
    }
    
    public static Integer GenerarNumero(){
        Integer numero = null;
        
        numero = new Random().nextInt(1, 101);
        
        return numero;
    }

}
```

Y la clase cliente:

```
public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Socket canal = null;
        final Integer PUERTO = 2000;

        Integer numeroPropuesto = null;
        Integer numAuxMin = null;
        Integer numAuxMax = null;
        Integer min = 1;
        Integer max = 101;

        String mensajeRecibido = null;

        boolean salir = false;

        DataInputStream dis = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;

        while (!salir) {

            System.out.println("Comenzando el juego");

            try {
                canal = new Socket("localhost", PUERTO);

                numeroPropuesto = GenerarNumeroPropuesto(min, max);

                dis = new DataInputStream(canal.getInputStream());
                dos = new DataOutputStream(canal.getOutputStream());
                numAuxMin = 1;
                numAuxMax = 101;
                
                while (!salir){
                    dos.writeInt(numeroPropuesto);
                    mensajeRecibido = dis.readUTF();
                    
                    if (mensajeRecibido.equalsIgnoreCase("mayor")){
                        
                        numeroPropuesto = new Random().nextInt(numeroPropuesto, numAuxMax);
                        numAuxMin = numeroPropuesto;
                        System.out.println("Numero: " + numeroPropuesto);
                        dos.writeInt(numeroPropuesto);
                    } else if (mensajeRecibido.equalsIgnoreCase("menor")){
                        
                        numeroPropuesto = new Random().nextInt(numAuxMin, numeroPropuesto);
                        numAuxMax = numeroPropuesto;
                        System.out.println("Numero: " + numeroPropuesto);
                        dos.writeInt(numeroPropuesto);
                    } else if (mensajeRecibido.equalsIgnoreCase("bingo")){
                        salir = true;
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int GenerarNumeroPropuesto(Integer min, Integer max) {
        Integer numeroPropuesto = null;

        numeroPropuesto = new Random().nextInt(min, max);

        return numeroPropuesto;
    }
}
```

Mi intención es que servidor genere un número aleatorio entre 1 y 100 y el cliente vaya lanzando respuesta y el servidor vaya diciendo que es menor o mayor. Hasta que finalmente cliente adivina el número y se cierra. El servidor genera el número por si solo y el cliente genera las propuestas él solo.

Con el siguiente código solo genera un número el cliente y el programa no se para ni salta error. Tengo que detenerlo yo mismo. No se si ha entrado en bucle.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Y si el programa ha entrado en bucle, ¿cómo puedo saberlo?

Answer (score 1):

En la clase del servidor, tienes las siguientes líneas dentro del ciclo while:

```
Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
System.out.println("Conexión aceptada");
```

Lo que hace que el servidor este esperando una conexión nueva en cada vuelta del ciclo, por lo que no avanza. Si las sacas, el servidor funciona correctamente. Quedando el fragmento de código de la siguiente forma:

```
try {
    servidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);
    System.out.println("Esperando la conexión");

    numeroSecreto = GenerarNumero();
    System.out.println("Número secreto: " + numeroSecreto);

    Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
    System.out.println("Conexión aceptada");

    while(!acertado){

        dis = new DataInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
```

Como lo mencionan, tienes un error de lógica en la clase cliente, pero mi solución es diferente, te coloco como quedaría el fragmento de código:

```
if (mensajeRecibido.equalsIgnoreCase("mayor")) {
    numAuxMin = numeroPropuesto; //Antes de buscar otro número aleatorio
    numeroPropuesto = new Random().nextInt(numeroPropuesto, numAuxMax);
    System.out.println("Numero: " + numeroPropuesto);
    //dos.writeInt(numeroPropuesto);
} else if (mensajeRecibido.equalsIgnoreCase("menor")) {
    numAuxMax = numeroPropuesto; //Antes de buscar otro número aleatorio
    numeroPropuesto = new Random().nextInt(numAuxMin, numeroPropuesto);
    System.out.println("Numero: " + numeroPropuesto);
    //dos.writeInt(numeroPropuesto);
} else if (mensajeRecibido.equalsIgnoreCase("bingo")) {
    salir = true;
}
```

En el cuál se llenan las variables numAuxMin y numAuxMax antes de buscar otro número que mandar al servidor.De igual manera, se comenta la línea

```
dos.writeInt(numeroPropuesto);
```

Debido a que la tienes al principio del ciclo, y la estarías mandando 2 veces, lo que hace que se entre en un bucle.

¿Por qué si relleno el numAuxMin o el numAuxMax antes de generar el número aleatorio da error? Si colocas el valor de numAuxMin como el del nuevo número aleatorio, al venir de un MAYOR y en la siguiente iteracion recibir un MENOR, el método nextInt(), lo estaría haciendo con el mismo valor de numAuxMin y numeroPropuesto, por lo que falla, por lo que si el número que mandaste es 40, y el servidor devolvió un MAYOR, el número 40 debe ser el valor mínimo y no el nuevo que vas a generar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: perdona, cometí un error, no tiene un error de lógica, podrías editar tu respuesta y quitar el "tienes un error de lógica". gracias.

Comment: Pero en realidad, lo tiene, si coloca los valores a numAuxMin y numAuxMax después de sacar otro número aleatorío, falla.

Comment: Si saco esas dos líneas del bucle while funciona la clase Servidor. Fenomenal!! Gracias!!! Pero, ¿por qué es?

Comment: Y con respecto al error de lógica debe de ser porque me salta un error cuando me está calculando el número. Si realizo el cambio que me habéis dicho, funciona correctamente. ¿Por qué si relleno el numAuxMin o el numAuxMax antes de generar el número aleatorio da error?

Comment: Lo agregué a la respuesta, espero te sirva!

Comment: @JCV Muchísimas gracias! Eres un fenómeno.